# Not sure whats wrong with my java program that calculates average

Tags: java, average

Doing the Mooc course, I'm really new to programming, and I just do not understand why its telling me this is wrong. The averages for 4, 3, 6, 1 are correct, but when it tests 12, 2, 8, 0 the average is not correct.

```
public class Averaging {

    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        return number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
    }

    public static double average(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        int count = 0;
        if (number1 != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        if (number2 != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        if (number3 != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        if (number4 != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        double total = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4);
        double average = (double) total / count;
        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = average(4, 3, 6, 1);
        System.out.println("Average: " + result);
    }
}
```

Originally I had total = sum (4, 3, 6, 1); changed to total = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4); which solved some issues.

---

```java
average(4, 3, 6, 1)  // result: 3.5    ; expected: 3.5
average(12, 2, 8, 0) // result: 7.33333; expected: 5.5
```

Comment: When calculating an average, zeroes in the data set should be included in the count. For example, the average of [1, 5, 0] is deemed to be 6/3 = 2. It's not 6/2=3 (which is what your code would give, because you don't increment `count` when your number is 0).

Comment: Define "correct"? Your current function explicitly considers zeroes to not be a part of the dataset, so the average of (12,2,8,0) by your definition is 7.333. But the more conventional definition of "average" would put it at 5.5. Which result do you want?

Comment: What is the desired output? What is you output?

Comment: In an advanced step, you may wanna use `int... numbers`

Comment: So the issue is because im excluding zeroes, in what way could I count these numbers then? It would need to include every possible value.

Comment: You are explicitly excluding `0`. What do you think `if (number1 != 0)` is doing?

Comment: remove all that if statements checking for 0.  why do you think 0 should be excluded?

Comment: Why are you counting the numbers at all? You already know that you are averaging exactly 4 numbers, because that's the only way your function can be called.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do. Are you thinking that you might want to average only three numbers (let's say 10, 20 and 30), and to do that you would call `average(10, 20, 30, 0)`? That will be a problem, because what if one of the numbers actually is zero? If you want to average a flexible number of values, then the function should accept an array of numbers, rather than exactly 4 arguments.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean

Comment: an interesting moment when old and new programmer meets

Answer (score 1):

A few things here :

- You need to include zeroes when calculating averages.
- Your method requires 4 numbers to be called, so you do not need to count them. It will always be 4.

Try this instead :

```
public static double average(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
    double total = sum(number1, number2, number3, number4);    
    double average = (double) total / 4;
    return average;
    }
```

You could also put the numbers in an array and use the array length as your count, so that you wouldn't have to edit your divider if you need to calculate the average of 6 numbers instead of 4 eventually.

You would need a loop to go through the array and add up your numbers :

```
    int numbers[] = {12, 2, 8, 0};
    int total = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    total = total + numbers[i];
    }
    double average = total / numbers.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between

- "measure 3 times", i.e. "there's no 4th measurement" and
- "measure 4 times", where one of the measurements is actually `0`

That's what you've noticed as well, because the average of `12, 2, 8, 0` is certainly different from the average of `12, 2, 8`. The "average" takes *all* values into account.

I think what you're trying to achieve here is to call your average with a variable number of arguments, if I'm not mistaken.

In that case you should make use of [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) (See the section "*Arbitrary Number of Arguments*").

With varargs, you're basically passing any number of arguments to your method. Since varargs are treated as an array of values, you even have access to the *number* of arguments passed, so you can use that for calculating the average.

In the end, there's no magic involved here, just sum all values together and then divide by the number of values. No need for checking each number individually for `0` (which should not be ignored, as mentioned).

Depending on your knowledge so far, you'd need to learn about [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) as well, but the final code might look like this.

```
public static double average(int... values) {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        sum += values[i];
    }
    return sum / values.length;
}
```

And you'd call the method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double result = average(4, 3, 6, 1);
    System.out.println("Average: " + result);

    result = average(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8); // virtually any number of arguments is fine
    System.out.println("Average: " + result);
}
```